# While loop in QTP

Tags: while-loop, do-while, qtp

I'm trying to execute the while loop in QTP below

```
x = true
y = 2 
Do While x = True
Msgbox y
thing = RunAction "Action1",oneIteration, y
x = thing
y = y + 1
Loop
```

When I don't call the RunAction it will call "msgbox y" as it should, but when I include it the first Msgbox just does does not get called at all. It doesn't even display an empty msgbox. Action 1 ends up being called with its default number instead of y. Help!

Comment: How many times Action1 gets called?

Comment: Also, have you used error handling? If you have used statements like 'On Error Resume Next' or 'Proceed to Next Step' in QTP settings, please disable them to show any error.

Comment: Do you intend to store the output of Action1 in the variable "thing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `ctrl + F7` to see any syntax error in QTP.
If you return a value, you should use () for the functions.

Retry as shown here and share what you find.

```
Do While x = True
  Msgbox y
  x= RunAction("Action1",oneIteration, y)
  y = y + 1
Loop
```